# MVC 3: ActionFilterAttribute and OnActionExecuting don't fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, events

I am trying to add a `WarningCheck` attribute to my model, where I'd override the    `OnActionExecuting` to control the validation. The problem is the code is never called.

**`WarningCheckAttribute`**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)] // I have tried other targets too without success
public class WarningCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

      /* DO SOME STUFF */
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
  public class Ticket   
   {
    ...
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il Cliente è obbligatorio.")]
    [WarningCheck]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Il nome del Cliente può essere al massimo di 20 cifre."), MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Il nome del Cliente è troppo corto. Inserire almeno 3 caratteri.")]
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name says, **Action** FilterAttribute should be applied to **Actions**, not properties.

```
[WarningCheck]
public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am newbie.

Comment: @Larry You should check out at least some video tutorials out there. Validation is done in better way than using action filters

Comment: THX archil. Any tutorial suggestion, pls?